# Como enviar un email con PHP y MySQL incluyendo resultados de un select?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un envió de un `email` de acuerdo a los resultados de un `select` en una base hecha en `mysql`, la cosa es que sale el correo pero llega solo la tabla `html` sin los resultados, este es mi código:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("","","");


if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
  mysqli_select_db("", $con);
  $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM fco");
  $to = "fran@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Resultado Query";
  $body = "<table border='1'>;
  $body .=<tr>
  $body .=<th>fecha:</th>
  $body .=<th>supervisor:</th>
  $body .=<th>id_cliente:</th>
  $body .=<th>nombre:</th>
  $body .=</tr>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
  $body .="<tr>";
  $body .="<td>". $row['fecha'] . "</td>";
  $body .="<td>". $row['supervisor'] . "</td>";
  $body .="<td>". $row['id_cliente'] . "</td>";
  $body .="<td>". $row['nombre'] . "</td>";
  $body .="</tr>";
  }
  $body .="</table>";
  mysqli_close($con);

  $headers = "From: fran@gmail.com";
  mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
  echo "Mail Enviado a $to";
?>
```

Evidencia del correo llegada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($row);` dentro del `while` para ver si está trayendo datos realmente y cómo vienen esos datos.

Comment: Lo hize y llega igual el mail!! :(

Comment: cuando escribes el email antes de enviar.. te trae los datos de la base de datos?

Comment: @francisco_hid lo que preguntaba Cedano es justamente si ves que el var_dump arroja datos o no.. el mail va a seguir sin funcionar. var_dump lo unico que hace es mostrarte el contenido de una variable

Comment: lo que pasa que el archivo se ejecuta sin tener una llamada de datos antes, solo lo ejecuto cuando abro la url con el archivo y cuando se ejecuta el mail ya salio. la ides es meter el archivo en un cron para luego programarlo y se ejecute la query y se envie al correo.

Comment: Francisco no entiendo cuál es tu problema entonces, ahora nos hablas de otro tema, de meter la ejecución del script en un cron. Pero quedamos en que el email se manda sin datos, ¿eso ya quedó resuelto? Cuando resuelvas eso entonces puedes pasar al tema del cron, pero en otra pregunta y previa investigación. Si pones el `var_dump` y ejecutas el archivo que manda el email por URL verás en pantalla si `$row` trae datos o no, eso es lo 1º que habría que depurar.

Comment: debes agregar las etiquetas `<html></html>`. Prácticamente es como crear una mini web sin embargo hay que entender que dependendiendo de a quien envies`(outlook, gmail, ...etc.)` hay restricciones`(html, css, estilos en linea)` el ejemplo de @Diego Avila es el mas cercano de los veo, solo debes agregar dentro del `body` tu `table` dado que te dejo solo con datos de prueba. Espero te sirva saludos 

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes, está en las comillas dobles que le faltan a tu código.
En la línea donde dice table-border, te faltan las comillas dobles al final de la sentencia. Igual al principio y al final de las 6 siguientes líneas.
Espero que se me entienda y haber ayudado en algo...

Answer (score -1):

Saludos puedes hacer algo asi:

```
$to = 'ejemplo@email.com';
$subject = 'Hola Mundo';
$from = 'micorreo@email.com';

//para enviar correo con HTML debe establecer los headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hola mundo!</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Esto es una prueba StackOverflow</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

//enviando el correo
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Correo enviado con éxito!';
} else{
    echo 'Error al enviar!';
}
```

Para mayor detalle te sugiero leer la documentación: [Mail PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: y donde agregar la consulta?

Comment: tu consulta va como parte de "$message",..alli armas el mensaje a enviar..!!

Comment: no entiendo donde va el query....

Comment: El problema del OP no es que llegue el email, sino que incluya los datos que necesita.

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que uses phpmailer.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
 try {



        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);          
            //Server settings
        $mail->isSMTP();       
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'example@example.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('example@example.com', 'name');

        if(is_array($this->Emails)){
            foreach($this->Emails as $email){
                $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
            }
        }
        else{
            $mail->addAddress($this->Emails);     // Add a recipient
        }

        if(isset($this->Attachments)){

            if(is_array($this->Attachments)){
                foreach($this->Attachments as $Attachment){
                    $mail->addAttachment($Attachment);         // Add attachments
                }
            }
            else{
                $mail->addAttachment($this->Attachments);         // Add attachments
            }

        }

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $this->Subject;
        $mail->Body    = $this->Body;

        $mail->send();
        return true;
```

Comment: y donde agregar la consulta?

Comment: Si te das cuenta es una clase de Mail en donde toma los datos y envía a ciertos correos con sus template  y archivos correspondientes, si no sabe hacer una consulta a la base de datos te recomiento formular una pregunta con ese tema.

Comment: El problema del OP no es que llegue el email, sino que incluya los datos que necesita.

Answer (score -1):

lo probé en el servidor , funciona ok

```
   <?php
         $con = mysqli_connect("","","");


         if (!$con)
             {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
                       }
       mysqli_select_db($con , "" );

       $query_result = "SELECT * FROM fco";

       $result = mysqli_query($con, $query_result) or 
        die(mysqli_error($con));
        $row_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

       $to = "fran@gmail.com";
       $subject = "Resultado Query";

       //logre que enviara bien la tabla con los siguientes "headers"

       $headers ='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
       $headers .='Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

       //comienzo el mensaje en html

        $body = "<table border='1'>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCFFFF' >
        <th>fecha:</th>
        <th>supervisor:</th>
        <th>id_cliente:</th>
        <th>nombre:</th>
     </tr>";
     //acá cierro html para insertar php iniciar el bucle
   
             do {

     // luego sigue body con html mezclado con valores mysql con php

     $body .="<tr>
    <td>".$row_result['fecha']."</td>
    <td>".$row_result['supervisor']."</td>
    <td>".$row_result['id_cliente']."</td>
    <td>".$row_result['nombre']."</td>
  </tr>";
    //cerramos html nuevamente para insertar php para completar el bucle

     }   while($row_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));

    // termina con body con html para cerrar la tabla

  $body .="</table>";

  mysqli_close($con);

 if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){  // ponemos condición si se envía
  
    echo "Mail Enviado a ".$to."<br>";  // echo también mezcla html con 
   valores en php

   echo $boby;} //  lo puse para ver la tabla que fue enviada

    ?>
```

Comment: Considera añadir enunciados explicando cómo tu código puede ayudar

Comment: Como te dijeron, agregale una explicacion a tu codigo.

Comment: edita la respuesta y agrega una explicación en el cuerpo de tu respuesta, los comentarios no son para dar respuesta, argumentarlas o contextualizarlas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, te invito a leer [answer]. Ya te han dado las sugerencias adecuadas, puedes hacer clic en [edit] para añadir lo necesario a tu respuesta y que la misma sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.